# lubridate tz/CCTZ errors on one windows 10 machine but not another?

Tags: r, lubridate

The following code produces the errors shown on my laptop running windows 10, but runs fine on a desktop running windows 10 with identical R/lubridate set up. Any ideas what might be causing this?

```
> library(lubridate)

Attaching package: ‘lubridate’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    date, intersect, setdiff, union

> Sys.getenv("TZDIR")
[1] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.1/share/zoneinfo"
> lubridate::force_tz(ymd_hm("2021-03-01 10:40"), tz="UTC")
[1] "2021-03-01 10:40:00 UTC"
> lubridate::force_tz(as.POSIXct("2021-03-01 10:40"), tz="UTC")
Error: CCTZ: Unrecognized timezone of the input vector: ""
> 
> lubridate::force_tz(ymd_hm("2021-03-01 10:40"), tz=Sys.timezone())
Error: CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: "Australia/Sydney"
> 
> R.version
               _                                
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32               
arch           x86_64                           
os             mingw32                          
crt            ucrt                             
system         x86_64, mingw32                  
status                                          
major          4                                
minor          2.1                              
year           2022                             
month          06                               
day            23                               
svn rev        82513                            
language       R                                
version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
nickname       Funny-Looking Kid                
> packageVersion("lubridate")
[1] ‘1.8.0’
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This sounds strange. Perhaps  including the sessionInfo from both machines could help.

Comment: sessionInfo is identical for both except. 



Working Machine
"loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] compiler_4.2.1 httr_1.4.3     R6_2.5.1      "

Not Working Machine
"loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] compiler_4.2.1 tools_4.2.1"

Comment: Only other difference between setups I can think of is working one is behind a proxy (in office). The laptop can be both behind proxy or at home and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore. I deleted and reinstalled lubridate package. And now it works on my laptop. No idea what was going on. Sorry to have wasted your time!

Comment: For what it's worth, this issue has popped up on the GitHub issues before and apparently been resolved by some updates, so I guess it's expected that *some* versions might suffer this issue.

Comment: Funny thing tho is it was version 1.8.0 both times I installed.